# Applying my mobile masterpage

Tags: master-page, redirect, mobile

My wish is to have mobile devices using my mobile friendly master page and regular browsers using the current v4.master-page. There's compleytly different content on these masterpages. I've tried a few different routes but I haven't got any of them to work as I want.

When I enter **mysite/Pages/default.aspx** in a browser I get our standard view, and if I enter the same URL in a mobile device I'm redirected to **mysite/_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx**.

My first thought was to apply my mobile.master to mbllists.aspx, but that didn't seem to work. It says:
*The referenced file '/_catalogs/masterpage/mobile.master' is not allowed on this page.*

So I thought I might be able to redirect mobile devices to another page, instead of mbllists.aspx. I tried the following example which creates an http module that redirects mobile devices to a custom master page. But I couldn't figure out where to add this Http module? see [reference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ashush/creating-a-sharepoint-portal-for-mobile/)

My third option was to disable mobile redirection in the **compat.browser** file. Now our regular master page is also viewed in a mobile device, but how do I add code to redirect to my mobile.master in the v4.master? And where do I put this code and referencing it in the v4.master?

Is there another easier approach to get this working at all or am I on the right track?

I should say that I'm fairly new to Sharepoint and its structure. I've taken a 4 day course in how to program in Sharepoint, but administrating it like this is still pretty tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest to you for the mobile view is to use a responsive design, you just need one masterpage and the css will adjust the content to the size of the browser based on media queries.

to follow this approach you will have to disable the mobile view, here is a well explained method http://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/how-to-disable-mobile-view-in-sharepoint-2010/

You can search for responsive themes for SharePoint there are a few out there.

Here you have one example of a responsive theme for SharePoint http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010/theme/SPC

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Create Design Channels for each one of the mobile devices you want
   to override the behavior and use your master page.
2. Deactivate the "Mobile Browser View" feature so all mobile devices
   will use the full site experience. (Note:  This feature is site
   scoped.)